# How to give a warning message before going to empty record?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

When I am navigating through records in my form I want to be informed when I click on next button that there are no more records (if there are no more records, ofc). By default in access, I am first shown a blank record and when I click again warning message.

Going through the record:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/IaS4J]

Going into an empty record:

[image]

Getting a warning message when clicking on next for the second time:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to disable the button when the user reaches the new record:

```
Private Sub Form_Current

    Me!ButtonNext.Enabled = Not Me.NewRecord

End If
```

Comment: I am having a problem with this currently, what part of the code should I replace with my own? I have replaced ButtonNext with name how is called in my database. Currently the button is not working at all.

Comment: It probably shouldn't replace anything, just be inserted in that event. But only you will know ...

Comment: It's working now, but it's just avoiding last message, I am still getting empty record( as shown on 2nd picture)

Comment: That must be caused by something else than clicking the button.